# Weird Network Manager Issue in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am experiencing a weird problem with mobile broadband connections... I installed a fresh copy on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit) along with the already installed Windows 7 on my laptop. I created a mobile broadband connection in Edit Connects. All works well except enable mobile broadband connection is missing from the network menu. I tried several solutions from SO and AskUbuntu with no luck. I also have two other desktops running the 32 bit version with Windows 7 dual boot with no issues. So I removed and reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit) but the issue still persist. My device in the output of lsusb. All three installations are from the same image so I guess no package is missing.

**The weird part :** 

If I connect through windows and then reboot in Ubuntu without removing the device, enable mobile broadband option gets displayed and I am able to connect. However, If I disconnect or re-plug the device, the menu option again disappears.

I am using Huawei EC-306-1 usb stick with MTS MBlaze connection. 

**lsusb output :**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6483 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**usb-devices output :**

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0c45 ProdID=6483 Rev=0b.16
S:  Manufacturer=CNFA151F304010001862
S:  Product=Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0024 Rev=00.00
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=046d ProdID=c05a Rev=63.00
S:  Manufacturer=Logitech
S:  Product=USB Optical Mouse
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:0b:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1506 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Huawei Technologies
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
C:  #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=10 Driver=option
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=12 Driver=option
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=13 Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=03.13
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:0b:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the modem in Ubuntu because it has multiple modes. When you boot to Windows it switches it to another mode.

The default mode is the network card mode. It is possible to use it in this mode in Ubuntu, but it requires manual configuration and connecting/disconnecting in CLI. Scripting can help.

I suspect that the version of Network Manager supports it in Ubuntu 15.05, but I did not test it yet.

The easiest solution is to switch the modem to "modem" mode. It can be done by running in terminal

```
echo -e 'AT^SETPORT="A1,A2;10,12,13,A2"\r' | sudo tee  /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Then replug the modem and wait for about 20 seconds for it to boot. Then the option in Network Manager will appear.

Disadvantage of this is that in Windows, if you use the vendor connection software, it may not work. But you can setup a telephone connection in Windows instead.

But it looks like your Windows switches the modem to a good mode for linux, so it should not be a problem.

This setting can always be reverted by running

```
echo -e 'AT^SETPORT="A1,A2;12,16,A1,A2"\r' | sudo tee  /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was indeed the problem with usb_modswitch. I am not sure which solution worked for me as I compare my usb_modswitch logs with a working connection and tried various other solutions from SO and askUbuntu , However, it looked like usb_modswitch was sometimes switching successfully but somehow failing to find the serial device afterwards and sometimes it completely fails in switching.

Comment: @Jayant I am now writing from exactly same modem :-) It works perfectly after manually switched to modem mode.